# Firebase value event listener in python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code

```
public static class Post {

    public String author;
    public String title;

    public Post(String author, String title) {
    }

}

// Get a reference to our posts
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        System.out.println(post);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

I would like to write it in python. But it seems that Firebase library for python doesn't support it? Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `stream()` do this for Python ([Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase))?

Comment: could you provide example ?